# Get annotation name using Apache Bcel

Tags: java, annotations, bcel

I'm using this code to get Java Class annotation:

```java
JavaClass jclas = new ClassParser("src\\test\\org\\poc\\TestClass.class").parse();

ClassGen cg = new ClassGen(jclas);

AnnotationEntryGen[] attributes = cg.getAnnotationEntries();

for (AnnotationEntryGen attribute : attributes) {
    System.out.println("attribute: " + attribute);
    if(attribute.getTypeName().contains("Fix")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But when I print `attribute.getTypeName()` I get `Lorg/annotations/Fix`. The annotation name is `@Fix(..)`
Do you know how I can get only the name?

Answer (score 0):

A string like `"Lorg/annotations/Fix" is a *field descriptor*.
Java has [many different formats](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#signature-annotations) for class names.

You can convert among the different formats for a name using the [`Signatures` class](http://plumelib.org/reflection-util/api/org/plumelib/reflection/Signatures.html) of the [reflection-util package](https://github.com/plume-lib/reflection-util).

> The annotation name is `@Fix(..)`.

That terminology is incorrect; you have shown how the full annotation is written in Java source code, but that is not its name.  `getTypeName()` really did return its name (in field descriptor format).

If you want the annotation's elements (which appear between the parentheses when the annotation is written in Java source code), use [`getValues()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/AnnotationEntryGen.html#getValues--).  You might also find [`toString()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/AnnotationEntryGen.html#toString--) useful.